# How to enable looping in pagination swiper?

Tags: pagination, swiper.js

How can I enable infinite looping through the images in the pagination swiper?

```
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            loop: true,  <----- doesnt work
            clickable: true,
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use loop in pagionation.

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
 });
```

Notice `loop` properties is set to `true`